# how to get all the sharepoint web applications on sharepoint server programatically

Tags: sharepoint, web-applications

Is there any way to get the list of all the web applications created in a sharepoint server?

I have to use either client object model or web services

Answer (score 2):

MSDN shows how to enumerate all web applications in the farm right on [`SPFarm`'s overview page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm.aspx):

```
SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;
SPWebService service = farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>("");
foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in service.WebApplications)
{
    …
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ondrej. Forgot to mention that I dont want to use server object model. I can use either web service or client object mode.